# Python: Variables in def

Tags: python

So I'm trying to build a gambling simulator in python and I have hit a wall when trying to charge my players 3 of the currency to select a game. This is my code so far:

```
import time
import random

money=10
games=0

while money < 1:
  print("Game over")

def start():

  print('Welcome to my gambling simulator! You have 10^ (the currency)') 
  print("\n")

def game_choice():
  answer = input("Which game would you like to play? (spinner [3 monies] ,")
  print("\n")
  if answer == "spinner":
    money=money-3  # <----------This bit dosen't work!
    spinner()

def spinner():
  print("\n")
  print("greetings")

  print(money)

#Actual stuff
start()
game_choice()
```

Comment: what exactly is your issue in the code?

Comment: Please specify as to why it should not work?

Comment: you are calling spinner method before declaring it.

Comment: You have to define "money" before it is getting used

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend not using a `global` variable like money. instead it would be a better code design to initiate the money variable at `start` and pass it to each iteration of game choice, in this way you can change it according to each new "game" you add. i would suggest something like this:

```
import time
import random 

def start():

  # initiate session variables:
  money=10
  games=0
  print(f'Welcome to my gambling simulator! You have {money}^ (the currency)')
  print("\n")
  return money, games

def game_choice(money, games):
  answer = input("Which game would you like to play? (spinner [3 monies] ,")
  print("\n")
  if answer == "spinner":
    money -= 3
    games += 1
    spinner(money)
  return money, games

def spinner(money):
  print("\n")
  print("greetings")

  print(money)

#Actual stuff
money, games = start()
money, games = game_choice(money, games)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your game_choice() func to let the func know that you are going to use a global variable and it wont create one in local scope.

```
def game_choice():

  # using a global keyword 
  global money

  answer = input("Which game would you like to play? (spinner [3 monies] ,")
  print("\n")
  if answer == "spinner":
    money=money-3               
    spinner()
```

Explanation : Python will create a local scope variable if it doesn't find one and it wont look for a global scoped variable. By adding `global` keyword before `money` variable, you tell python to look for the money variable in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that in Python variable declaration is *implicit* and *local* by default.

That is, by default, when you assign to a variable it's implicitly *declared* in the current scope. This means

```py
def game_choice():
  answer = input("Which game would you like to play? (spinner [3 monies] ,")
  print("\n")
  if answer == "spinner":
    money=money-3               <----------This bit dosen't work!
    spinner()
```

Since you're assigning to `money` and even though you're also *using* money, Python will implicitly declare `money` as a local variable. Then it will blow up when trying to *read* money, because it has not been assigned to in the local scope (and the local declaration "hides" the global).

There are a few ways to fix this issue, of various cleanliness and forward-vision:

- The simpler one is to add a `global money` at the start of the function, as I noted above *by default* variables are local, this declaration overrides the default and tells Python "actually this variable should be accessed globally even when assigning to it". This would work fine for a simple script, however mutable global variables tend to be error-prone and difficult to manage as programs grow and more and more functions start messing with them, it becomes hard to understand why they have the value they do.
- A second one would be to have `game_choice` take `money` as a parameter and possibly return it afterwards, that way there's no global involved and you can easily and tightly control how things are accessed, this also makes it easier to *test* the function, as you can give it e.g. 0 or insufficient or large or negative amounts of money and check that it reacts properly.
- The final option is to create a *class* (e.g. `Game`), have game choice be a *method* and money be an *instance variable*, part of the gamestate. A method can always access and modify instance variables, and you still have a tighter handle than with global variables because all the game state is in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

First, you use spinner before you define it. Move spinner up. Second, there is a

> while money < 1

Line in the beginning of your source, it will stuck there. Remove that. Third, put

> global money

Into game_choice, but an easier way is to pass values to a function, it processes it, then the value gets returned. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the `global` keyword to modify variables defined outside your function.

```
def game_choice():
  answer = input("Which game would you like to play? (spinner [3 monies] ,")
  print("\n")
  if answer == "spinner":
    global money
    money=money-3
    spinner()
```